# Not Getting expected result in multi-threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm not getting expected result for below program, I was expecting both producer and consumer method should execute in some sequence, but for some reason only producer method is getting executed.

I have two question here :

1. I'm not able to understand this behaviour.
2. Joining both thread together in last line of main method is working properly, I'm not able to understand difference between both.

   ```
   public class ProducerConsumer {
       List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();

        synchronized void  produce() throws InterruptedException {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               System.out.println("Producing");
               data.add(i);
           }
           wait();
       }

       synchronized void consume() throws InterruptedException {
               System.out.println("Consuming");
               data.clear();
               notify();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
           ProducerConsumer pc = new ProducerConsumer();

           Runnable r2 = ()-> {
               try {
                   pc.produce();
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           };
           Thread thread1 = new Thread(r2);
           thread1.start();
           thread1.join();




           Runnable r1 = () -> {
               try {
                   pc.consume();
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           };
           Thread thread = new Thread(r1);
           thread.start();
           thread.join();

       }
   ```

   *Output : 
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing
   Producing*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A `notify()` call does not do *anything at all*. Unless some other thread is *already waiting* to be notified.

It's up to you to guarantee that any time one of your threads calls `wait()`, some other thread will `notify()` the same object some time *after* the `wait()` has begun.

Oracle's [Guarded Blocks Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) does a pretty good job of explaining exactly how `o.wait()` and `o.notify()` work, and it explains how to establish that guarantee.

2) There is virtually no reason to do this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
t.join();
```

Your program will use less CPU, and it will use less memory, and it will accomplish exactly the same thing if you just call `r.run()` instead. The *entire point* of threads is to allow different things to happen *[concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))*, and there is no concurrency if one thread `joins` a new thread immediately after creating it.  The new `Thread` object is wasted unless you do something like this with it:

```
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
doSomethingElseWhileThread_t_isRunning();
t.join();
```

3) `wait()` and `notify()` are a very low-level means of communicating between threads. Your code will be easier to read and understand if you use [higher-level synchronization objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html) that are built on top of `wait()` and `notify()` instead of directly 
 calling them.

A [`java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) instance would be especially well suited to a "producer/consumer" application.

Answer (score 1):

The `produce()` method ends with `wait()`. So it blocks until some thread notifies it.

The only thread that does that is the consumer thread. But the consumer thread is started by the main method only after the producer thread has ended. And it can't end until it's been notified. So you have a deadlock.

If you `join()` only after the two threads are started, then the consumer thread can start without having to wait for the producer thread to be finished. That still doesn't make the program correct since

- you have no guarantee that the producer thread will execute first
- calling wait() at then end is useless
- calling wait() out of a loop checking for a condition is incorrect
- if you want methods to execute in sequence, using threads is useless. You can do everything from the main thread.